# In Lost Legacy, how do you locate the photo op locations?

Tags: uncharted-lost-legacy

I'm in Chapter 5 and still haven't figured out the photo op locations.  I've encountered several, purely by chance. Is there a more direct way to know where the locations are at?  Or is it randomly running around the map until the indicator appears onscreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience, the only way to find these is to be notified when you're near one. There are no indicators from a distance like there are for the treasures. However, for the most part, these photo ops aren't too far off from the main path you're supposed to take, but a few are a little ways off.

That said, you don't have to blindly run around looking for these photo ops. There are multiple guides (with images) around that tell you where all of them are. Here are some examples:

- [Eurogamer photo op guide](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-09-15-uncharted-the-lost-legacy-collectibles-guide-treasure-photo-lockbox-conversation-4934?page=3)
- [IGN photo op guide](http://m.ign.com/wikis/uncharted-the-lost-legacy/Photo_Ops)
- [ShackNews photo op guide](http://www.shacknews.com/article/101133/uncharted-the-lost-legacy---all-photo-opportunities)

If you want to find them yourself without explicitly using a guide, it may help to know how many photo ops are in each chapter, so you know when you can stop looking (or know when you need to keep searching).

- Prologue:       **1**
- Chapter 2:     **1**
- Chapter 3:     **3**
- Chapter 4:     **9**
- Chapter 5:     **4**
- Chapter 6:     **2**
- Chapter 7:     **7**
- Chapter 8:     **1**